# Black overlay background appears when toggled

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, toggle

So I have this [jsfiddle.net/sn7Ny](http://jsfiddle.net/sn7Ny/), which I based from [this](http://jsfiddle.net/yrM3H/2/) it works perfectly fine except that when I use an iPad or iPhone, and I clicked on a question, a black background appears out of nowhere on that question. Is it an iPad / iPhone glitch? How do I remove this?

Here's my css

```
.item {
  font: 12px Arial
}

.item .toggle{
 color: #555;
 font-weight: 700;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0.5em 0em 0.5em 2em;
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 95%;
 text-align: left
}


.item .toggle:hover,
.item .active {
 background: rgb(242,242,242);
 width: 95%;
 border-radius: 100px;
 -moz-border-radius: 100px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
 position: relative
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: In your html, have you set a metatag for the viewport? This could result in the unexpected positioning.

Comment: I do not see this problem on my iPad. I take the back, I see what you mean now. I will have a little look into it.